# Domain wont resolve after adding SSL from cloudflare

Tags: ssl, dns, cloudflare

I added my website to cloudflare for SSL and after changing the nameservers to cloudflare's one (one's i have been assigned) Domain wont resolve

domain is harjeev98.cf

here is a screenshot of the setup i have done in cloudflare [click](http://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/2y3Z0M0x3L1Q0S0n3E3j/Image%202017-02-06%20at%202.42.11%20PM.png?v=03fe3ddf)

Comment: Your domain seems to resolve just fine when I look at it, so either it was just a matter of waiting for DNS changes to propagate, or you have to be more specific about the problem you see.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i resolved it by pointing SSL to root directory in cloudflare.
Thanks.